# Сортировка по нескольким условиям

Tags: sql

ххх.хххххххx.ru/Webххххх/Webххххх.aspx?dlrid=47&ppak=100&lang=Ru-ru

Нужно задать условие: ppak не равен 104 и не равен 106.

Answer (score 1):

ppak not in (104, 106)